# The difference between .mk file and Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, android.mk

I came across an unfamiliar type of file which is an `.mk` file. It appears to be an extension of Makefile but I don't know whether it is actually different from a Makefile. Can somebody help clarify the difference?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

A `make` file can have any name. The `-f` option of `make` is used to specify which file to use:

```
make -f foobar
```

You can even use `-f` several times:

```
make -f foo -f bar
```

In which case `make` processes the files in order (or, equivalently, concatenates the files and processes the result).

`makefile` and `Makefile` are special names because if `make` is called without the `-f` option it automatically searches for them, in this order, and use the first it finds. Note that GNU `make` also considers `GNUmakefile`, and prefers it over `makefile` and `Makefile`. Other `make` implementations can have other default names.

The `.mk` extension is a more or less standard extension for make files that have other names than the defaults. It is a reasonable extension if you want humans to quickly understand what these files are: `convert.mk` is more informative than `foobar`. Some editors use this extension to identify the file type and apply syntax coloring. They usually apply the same syntax coloring to `makefile` and `Makefile`.

Comment: Another common convention is to have a top-level `Makefile` which contains some logic to decide whether then to `include` one or more of `windows.mk`, `linux.mk`, or `mac.mk` (for example).